# What's so special about this PNG file?

Tags: ios, png, multipartform-data

This PNG [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/130266/test.png) can not be uploaded from my app to a 3d-party server. It always reports this error:

> does multipart has image?

I'm sure multipart encoding is correct. Tens of thousands of images are uploaded from my app without this issue. It it the first time.

I guess there is something special about this PNG file and I proved it:

1. Dropbox iOS app can not display the image.
2. Tweetbot can not upload it. The error message is "media type unrecognized".

So this PNG file is indeed special and quite some apps and servers don't handle it properly. But I don't know what's so special about it and hope someone who know PNG better than me can help. Thanks.

Comment: I downloaded and opened it, and it is perfectly fine and valid (shows a female face on a large black background)

Comment: @Aganju you can just try opening it in browser. Did you down-vote it?

Comment: FYI, I tried to open it in Adobe LightRoom (CC 2015) and it also says it's *"unsupported format"* (I did *not* downvote it - why would I)

Comment: @Aganju OK. Thanks. But many software can handle it including web browsers and OS X system. Actually my app can display it properly. It is just when uploading to server that the issue occurs. I guess in my case it is the server that can not handle this PNG file. Anyway there must be something odd about this PNG file and I want to know it.

Comment: You keep saying that the problem lies with uploading the file to your server. It does not. However, *Apple* software can display it because most likely they use a shared code base (including, as you say yourself, your mobile device and local browsers and viewers) but conforming PNG viewers cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [CgBI](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format) file, not a PNG, most likely made with Apple's rogue modified pngcrush.

Such files always contain "CgBI" in bytes 12-15, where "IHDR" belongs.

CgBI files can be converted to valid PNG files (except that the transparent areas are irreparably damaged) by several applications, including

- Jongware's [pngdefry](http://www.jongware.com/pngdefry.html)
- Apple's "pngcrush" (but not the real [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/))
- others listed on the above-referenced CgBI wiki page

Here are the first few bytes in your file:

```
$ od -c test.png | head -4
0000000 211   P   N   G  \r  \n 032  \n  \0  \0  \0 004   C   g   B   I
0000020   P  \0     002   + 325 263 177  \0  \0  \0  \r   I   H   D   R
0000040  \0  \0  \0   `  \0  \0  \0   `  \b 006  \0  \0  \0 342 230   w
0000060   8  \0  \0  \0       c   H   R   M  \0  \0   z   %  \0  \0 200
```

Those bytes represent the following:

```
PNG signature 0-7
CgBI length 8-11
"CgBI" 12-15
CgBI data 16-19
CgBI CRC 20-23
IHDR length 24-27 (should be in 8-11)
"IHDR" 28-31 (should be in 12-15)
width 32-35 (should be in 16-19)
height 36-39 (should be in 20-23)
bit depth 40 (should be in 24)
color type 41 (should be in 25)
compression 42 (should be in 26)
filter method 43 (should be in 27)
interlace method 44 (should be in 28)
IHDR CRC 45-48 (should be in 29-32)
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe it is the cause. Do you know whether the position of the four-byte critical chunk is fixed at 16~19 bytes or not? I need to correctly identify CgBI format so I can convert it to normal PNG.

Comment: The extra chunk is (apart from its peculiar illegal position) a regular PNG chunk. You can read the size as for any other PNG chunks.

Comment: Sorry I mislead you. CgBI should be in bytes 12-15.

Comment: I believe if you count again you'll see: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 0004 4367 4249.

Comment: Although it's kind of buried in the spec, it's quite clear: the IHDR chunk *shall be the first chunk* in the data stream. Thus, this file is not valid PNG. Some readers may not enforce this rule, and so will display it anyway.