# Not able to read IHDR chunk of a PNG file

Tags: swift, png, nsfilehandle

I have read PNG file specification and learnt that after the first 8 bytes of PNG signature, we have the IHDR chunk. This image states that we have IHDR with length of 13(0x0000000D) bytes. 
[image]

I have written a code in swift to read the same png file and print the bytes which does not give me an IHDR with length equal to 13 bytes from the first 4 bytes of the chunk after the PNG signature. The output of the code in console is

```
PNG Signature Bytes: 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 
File offset: 8
IHDR length bytes: 00 00 00 04 
File offset: 12
IHDR Chunktype bytes: 43 67 42 49 
File offset: 16
IHDR Data byte: 50 00 20 02 
File offset: 20
pngImageWidth: 1342185474
pngImageWidth: 20480
pngImageHeight: 8194
```

**Have I missed something here or the specification that I read was outdated?**

The first 8 bytes are infact PNG signature bytes. The IHDR bytes is where I dont get the expected length and chunk types(width, heigth and other bytes of the IHDR are variable for different files, but length and chunk types should be same as per my reading).

The code for reading the png file is straight forward and is as below:

```
enum PNGFileAnatomyConstants {
    static let pngSignatureLength = 8
    static let ihdrLength = 4
    static let chunkTypeLength = 4
    static let chunkCRCLength = 4
    static let imageWidthLength = 4
    static let imageHeigthLength = 4
}

func anatomyOfPNGFile() {
    let bundle = Bundle.main

    guard let pngFileUrl = bundle.url(forResource: "PNGFileSignature", withExtension: "png") else { fatalError() }

    do {
        // Signature start------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        let readFileHandle = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: pngFileUrl)
        defer {
            readFileHandle.closeFile()
        }
        let pngSignatureData = readFileHandle.readData(ofLength: PNGFileAnatomyConstants.pngSignatureLength)
        let signatureString  = pngSignatureData.hexEncodedString(options: [Data.HexEncodingOptions.upperCase])
        if signatureString != "89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A " {
            fatalError(" Not a png")
        }
        print("PNG Signature Bytes: \(signatureString)")
        print("File offset: \(readFileHandle.offsetInFile)")
        // Signature ebd------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




        // IHDR Length start------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        let ihdrLengthDataBigEndian = readFileHandle.readData(ofLength: PNGFileAnatomyConstants.ihdrLength)

        let ihdrLength: UInt32
        if PlatformEndianess.isLittleEndian {
            ihdrLength = Data(ihdrLengthDataBigEndian.reversed()).withUnsafeBytes({ (unsafePointer: UnsafePointer<UInt32>) -> UInt32 in
                return unsafePointer.pointee
            })
        } else {
            ihdrLength = ihdrLengthDataBigEndian.withUnsafeBytes({ (unsafePointer: UnsafePointer<UInt32>) -> UInt32 in
                return unsafePointer.pointee
            })
        }

        let ihdrLengthDataBigEndianString = ihdrLengthDataBigEndian.hexEncodedString(options: [.upperCase])
        print("IHDR length bytes: \(ihdrLengthDataBigEndianString)")
        print("File offset: \(readFileHandle.offsetInFile)")
        // IHDR Length end------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------





        // IHDR chunk type start------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        let ihdrChunkTypeData = readFileHandle.readData(ofLength: PNGFileAnatomyConstants.chunkTypeLength)
        let ihdrChunkTypeDataString  = ihdrChunkTypeData.hexEncodedString(options: [Data.HexEncodingOptions.upperCase])
        print("IHDR Chunktype bytes: \(ihdrChunkTypeDataString)")
        print("File offset: \(readFileHandle.offsetInFile)")
        // IHDR chunk type end------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



        // IHDR data byte start------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        let ihdrData = readFileHandle.readData(ofLength: Int(ihdrLength))
        let ihdrDataString = ihdrData.hexEncodedString(options: [.upperCase])
        print("IHDR Data byte: \(ihdrDataString)")
        print("File offset: \(readFileHandle.offsetInFile)")
        // IHDR data byte end------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        do {
            let pngImageWidth: UInt32
            if PlatformEndianess.isLittleEndian {
                pngImageWidth = Data(ihdrData.reversed()).withUnsafeBytes({ (unsafePointer: UnsafePointer<UInt32>) -> UInt32 in
                    return unsafePointer.pointee
                })
            } else {
                pngImageWidth = ihdrData.withUnsafeBytes({ (unsafePointer: UnsafePointer<UInt32>) -> UInt32 in
                    return unsafePointer.pointee
                })
            }

            print("pngImageWidth: \(pngImageWidth)")
        }

        do {
            let pngImageWidth: UInt16
            let widthData = Data(bytes: [ihdrData[0], ihdrData[1]])
            if PlatformEndianess.isLittleEndian {

                pngImageWidth = Data(widthData.reversed()).withUnsafeBytes({ (unsafePointer: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) -> UInt16 in
                    return unsafePointer.pointee
                })
            } else {
                pngImageWidth = widthData.withUnsafeBytes({ (unsafePointer: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) -> UInt16 in
                    return unsafePointer.pointee
                })
            }

            print("pngImageWidth: \(pngImageWidth)")//20480

            let pngImageHeight: UInt16
            let heightData = Data(bytes: [ihdrData[2], ihdrData[3]])
            if PlatformEndianess.isLittleEndian {

                pngImageHeight = Data(heightData.reversed()).withUnsafeBytes({ (unsafePointer: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) -> UInt16 in
                    return unsafePointer.pointee
                })
            } else {
                pngImageHeight = heightData.withUnsafeBytes({ (unsafePointer: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) -> UInt16 in
                    return unsafePointer.pointee
                })
            }

            print("pngImageHeight: \(pngImageHeight)")//20480
        }

    } catch {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

extension Data {
    struct HexEncodingOptions: OptionSet {
        let rawValue: Int
        static let upperCase = HexEncodingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    }

    func hexEncodedString(options: HexEncodingOptions = []) -> String {
        let hexDigits = Array((options.contains(.upperCase) ? "0123456789ABCDEF " : "0123456789abcdef ").utf16)
        var chars: [unichar] = []
        chars.reserveCapacity(3 * count)
        for byte in self {
            chars.append(hexDigits[Int(byte / 16)])
            chars.append(hexDigits[Int(byte % 16)])
            chars.append(hexDigits.last!)
        }
        return String(utf16CodeUnits: chars, count: chars.count)
    }
}

class PlatformEndianess {
    static var isLittleEndian: Bool = {
        var integer: UInt16 = 0x0001
        return withUnsafeBytes(of: &integer, { (rawBufferPointer) -> Bool in
            return rawBufferPointer.first == 0x01
        })
    }()
}
```

Comment: I tried your code with a PNG file, and it printed `IHDR length bytes: 00 00 00 0D` as you expect. Perhaps your file is corrupted?

Comment: @MartinR It could be possible that it is corrupted, but then other image viewers (say Preview on MacOS) open the file and show the image. Seems strange to me.

Comment: @MartinR I always read the length bytes from different png files to be 0x 00 00 00 04. Could it be a problem specific to my machine?

Comment: "43 67 42 49" is "CgBI", so your file is apparently not a regular PNG file, but a (Apple proprietary) [CgBI](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format)  file.

Comment: @MartinR thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. This question provides more light on the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473678/whats-so-special-about-this-png-file

Comment: @MartinR Could you please add an answer referring that apple has its own extension on PNG called CgBI. This would really help if some like me stumbles upon such files and is not able to make sense out of them.

Comment: Isn't everything already said in https://stackoverflow.com/q/34473678 ? We could close this as a duplicate. But I'll leave that up to you, you are welcome to add an (self-)answer here.

Comment: @MartinR It seems duplicate in terms of the information being conveyed. The questioner on the link is worried about why the server won't accept it. In my case my app is actually reading the png file. In the end it seems me and the questioner did not know about CgBI format. I also have the requirement of reading the bytes of this file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by [MartinR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) there exists an extension on PNG files called [CgBI](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format).

A normal PNG file has a structure where PNG signature is followed by IHDR chunk.

Below is an example of bytes in hex representation for a normal PNG file( xx are placeholders bytes with variable values):

```
PNG Signature(8 bytes): 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A
=======Chunk start=======
IHDR Chunk:
    IHDR chunk length(4 bytes): 00 00 00 0D
    IHDR chunk type(Identifies chunk type to be IHDR): 49 48 44 52
    Image width in pixels(variable 4): xx xx xx xx
    Image height in pixels(variable 4): xx xx xx xx
    Flags in the chunk(variable 5 bytes): xx xx xx xx xx
    CRC checksum(variable 4 bytes): xx xx xx xx 
=======Chunk end=======
```

A PNG file with CgBI extension has a structure where PNG signature is followed by CgBI chunk and then by IHDR chunk.

When I say extension don't confuse it for "filename.png, filename.cgbi". Its actually an extension of the way a PNG file is supposed to be structured.

Below is an example of bytes in hex representation for PNG file with CgBI extension( xx are placeholders bytes with variable values):

```
PNG Signature(8 bytes): 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A
=======Chunk start=======
CgBI Chunk:
    CgBI chunk length(4 bytes): 00 00 00 04
    CgBI chunk type(Identifies chunk type to be CgBI): 43 67 42 49
    CgBI info flags(4 bytes): xx xx xx xx
    CRC checksum(variable 4 bytes): xx xx xx xx 
=======Chunk end=======
=======Chunk start=======
IHDR Chunk:
    IHDR chunk length(4 bytes): 00 00 00 0D
    IHDR chunk type(Identifies chunk type to be IHDR): 49 48 44 52
    Image width in pixels(variable 4): xx xx xx xx
    Image height in pixels(variable 4): xx xx xx xx
    Flags in the chunk(variable 5 bytes): xx xx xx xx xx
    CRC checksum(variable 4 bytes): xx xx xx xx 
=======Chunk end=======
```

While PNG files are rendered on all image viewers, the extension CgBI maybe or may not be rendered on all image viewers depending on support they provide for such files.

MacOS preview can display such images and UIImageView on iOS is also able to display the files in my sample set of images(PNG with CgBI extension).