# Read PNG file with c

Tags: c, image, png

I want to read a PNG image file with C without any library. From [PNG (Portable Network Graphics) Specification Version 1.0](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2083) any PNG file has a signature that distinguishes it from other image formats. The signature is the first 8 bytes of the image.

Some sources like the above RFC mentioned the signature as:

> 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10 (decimal)

Or like [Not able to read IHDR chunk of a PNG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54845745/not-able-to-read-ihdr-chunk-of-a-png-file) mentioned the signature as:

> 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A (ASCii)

So, I write a simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE (8)

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <png file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    
    char *buf = (char *)malloc(MAX_SIZE);
    
    if(!buf) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    
    if(!f) {
        perror("fopen");
        printf("Invalid file\n");
        
        free(buf);
        return 1;
    }
    
    int size = fread(buf, 1, MAX_SIZE, f);

    printf(%c\n", buf[1]);
    printf(%c\n", buf[2]);
    printf(%c\n", buf[3]);
    printf(%c\n", buf[4]);
    printf(%c\n", buf[5]);
    printf(%c\n", buf[6]);
    printf(%c\n", buf[7]);
    printf(%c\n", buf[8]);
      fclose(f);
      free(buf);
    system("pause");
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I print the bytes by `printf`, the output is not like the above.
This is what it shows:

> ëPNG→►v@,

Can someone describe what happened and what can I do to modify it?

Comment: Please show how you "print the bytes by `printf`" and what you get, as that is not shown in the code. Note that the two signatures you show are the same: in decimal and in hexadecimal.

Comment: Your code doesn't printf anything...

Comment: Also use `fopen(argv[1], "rb");` for read binary

Comment: You need this somewhere: `for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) printf("%02x ", buf[i]);`

Comment: @WeatherVane I know it, I added them.

Comment: Re the edit a) your array indexing is wrong (should be `[0]` to `[7]`) and b) it's a binary file: don't output characters instead `printf(%d\n", buf[0]);` etc.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I did it and, It did not make any difference.

Comment: @WeatherVane The code I mentioned above is just a sample of all `printf` commands that I try. Obviously, I cant mentioned them. I also did your way and it did not work.

Comment: Yes, it's impossible to comment on what you haven't shown. I commented on what you did show, which is incorrect. The rest of the code seems to be correct.

Comment: You are not off to a good start. PNG is a complicated format, with deflate algorithm, pixel prediction methods, and various optimizations and specializations. Consider using a library instead.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani If I want to be honest, I know this, and I accepted this challenge.

Comment: You can start by learning Huffman coding, this is loss less compression also used in zip files. Write a pixel prediction algorithm (that shouldn't be too hard) and you have your own image format, probably not as good, but nearly as good as PNG. Then you have to match it exactly to PNG specification, that's actually harder, it's easier to copy existing libraries, or just add those files to your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print each value with the correct format specifier. Here we want numerical representations, not character ones.

From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) on `printf`:

- `%c` writes a single character
- `%d` converts a signed integer into decimal representation
- `%x` converts an unsigned integer into hexadecimal representation

`%02X` prints a hexadecimal with a minimum width of two characters, padding with leading zeroes, using *ABCDEF* (instead of *abcdef*).

See also [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions).

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 8

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned char magic[SIZE];
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if (!file || fread(magic, 1, SIZE, file) != SIZE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failure to read file magic.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Decimal */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d ", magic[i]);
    printf("\n");

    /* Hexadecimal */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("%02X ", magic[i]);
    printf("\n");

    fclose(file);
}
```

Output:

```
137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10 
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A
```

Comment: Really, I do your first print but did not work. I can't find why and also why "%02X" must work. Is the any more explantion?

Comment: @NULL *"did not work"* is not a useful [problem statement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In any case, I've updated the answer with more information about `printf` format specifiers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I learned what was needed.